# Javscript - If field contains any value show these fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using teh following script and it works for showing the 3 fields if someone types in the Last Name field.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
  $("#d_o_b1_field, #billing_phone_field, #gender1_field").hide();
  $("#billing_last_name_field").on('keyup', function(){
    $("#d_o_b1_field, #billing_phone_field, #gender1_field").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

We want the 3 fields to also show if there is any text in the last name field when the page loads. GPTchat recommended the following code but it does not work - the 3 fields are still hidden when the page loads - even when there is a value in the last name field.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#d_o_b1_field, #billing_phone_field, #gender1_field").hide();
  $("#billing_last_name_field").ready(function(){
    if($(this).val()){
      $("#d_o_b1_field, #billing_phone_field, #gender1_field").show();
    }
  });
  $("#billing_last_name_field").on('keyup', function(){
    $("#d_o_b1_field, #billing_phone_field, #gender1_field").show();
  });
});
```

Any ideas on why itis not working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `.on('keyup', )` function do a conditional show or hide based on the `billing_last_name_field` value. Then add a `.trigger('keyup')` to trigger that conditional code when the page is ready:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#d_o_b1_field, #billing_phone_field, #gender1_field").hide();
  $("#billing_last_name_field").on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
      $("#d_o_b1_field, #billing_phone_field, #gender1_field").show();
    } else {
      $("#d_o_b1_field, #billing_phone_field, #gender1_field").hide();
    }
  }).trigger('keyup');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<table>
<tr><td> Last Name: </td><td> <input id="billing_last_name_field" value="Smith" /></td></tr>
<tr><td> DOB: </td><td> <input id="d_o_b1_field" /></td></tr>
<tr><td> Phone: </td><td> <input id="billing_phone_field" /></td></tr>
<tr><td> Gender: </td><td> <input id="gender1_field" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi .. added your code and unfortunately it does not show the 3 fields when last name has a value. any ideas why it would nt be triggered?

Comment: Not sure why it does not work for you, did you run the code snipped here? Add a `console.log($(this).val())` inside the keyup function to verify its value